# Read one specific cell of numpy matrix

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

I wrote a function to see if a matrix is symmetric or not:

```
def issymmetric(mat):
    if(mat.shape[0]!=mat.shape[1]):
        return 0
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i):
            if (mat[i][j]!=mat[j][i]):
                return 0
    return 1
```

It works well with built-in ndarrays e.g. numpy.ones:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.ones((5,5), int)
print issymmetric(a)
```

And with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 1 , 2], [3, 2, 1]])
print issymmetric(a)
```

But when it comes to numpy matrixes:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [2, 1 , 2], [3, 2, 1]])
print issymmetric(a)
```

It gaves me this error:

```
  File "issymetry.py", line 9, in issymmetric
    if (mat[i][j]!=mat[j][i]):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 316, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

shell returned 1
```

That's because There is no a[0][1]

`a[0]` is `matrix([[1, 2, 3]])`. `a[0][0]` is `matrix([[1, 2, 3]])` too., but there is no `a[0][1]`.

How can I fix this issue, without changing the matrix type, or the function?

In general, what is the proper way to read and update one specific cell of a numpy matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to use `[i,j]` style indexing in `numpy`.  Often you can get by with `[i][j]` when using `np.array`, but not with `np.matrix`.  Remember an `np.matrix` is always 2d.

In a shell construct a simple 2d array, and try different methods of indexing.  Now try it with `np.matrix` arrays.  Pay attention to the shape.

```
In [2]: A = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [3]: A[1]   # short for A[1,:]
Out[3]: array([3, 4, 5])    # shape (3,)
In [4]: A[1][2]   # short for A[1,:][2]
Out[4]: 5
In [5]: M=np.matrix(A)
In [6]: M[1]
Out[6]: matrix([[3, 4, 5]])   # shape (1,3), 2d
In [7]: M[1][2]
...
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

correct indexing that works with both

```
In [9]: A[1,2]
Out[9]: 5
In [10]: M[1,2]
Out[10]: 5
```

`A[i][j]=...` is also prone to failure when used on the LHS.  It only works if the first part `A[i]` returns a `view`.  If fails if it produces a `copy`.